# Debug: Running Python Script from Windows task Manager

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run a Python program using Windows task Scheduler. At the stipulated time, I see a command window briefly appear and then disappear. However the Python script is supposed to create a file. That file is never created. I searched for the file using Windows search, but it is not located anywhere. However when I run the script using command line the file is created as intended. What am I doing wrong?

Following is my setup:

**Python program:
---------------------**

```
import os

print('start of simple test')
testList ="1,2,3"
with open('lala.txt', 'w') as testfile:
    testfile.write(testList)
```

**---------------------**

Following is the Actions setup in my Windows 7 Task Scheduler windows
Program/ Script: C:\Python\python.exe
Add arguments: "C:\PythonProject\ReportCreator.py"

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJjsW.jpg)

Comment: Maybe `lala.txt` is under `c:\Python` folder. Can you verify that it is not there?

Comment: No, I just checked it is not there. In fact I am searching using the Windows search window which you get by clicking the windows icon in the bottom left menu, this way I can locate the file anywhere, if it exists.

Comment: When the task is started, the current directory may be in a directory you don't have permission to create file.  Try either specifying the absolute path of the file `lala.txt` or specify a directory in the `Start in` setting of the scheduled task in `Task Scheduler`.

Answer (score 2):

You can see in which folder the scheduler is running your `ReportCreator.py` using this code. Create a python file `scheduler_path.py` and run it with the scheduler:

```
import os

print('current path:', os.path.abspath(os.curdir))
input('press enter to continue')  # input is for Python3. Use raw_input for Python2
```

It gave me this output: `current path: C:\WINDOWS\system32`. My guess is it is trying to write into system32 folder, but does not have permission to do that.

You can either give an absolute path to write the file, or if you want to create it at the same folder as your script file, you can do this:

```
import os

print('start of simple test')
test_list ='1,2,3'
script_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)  # in your case this should become C:\PythonProject\
filename = 'lala.txt'
filepath = os.path.join(script_folder, filename)
with open(filepath, 'wt') as test_file:
    test_file.write(test_list)
```